# Can update recovery partition of Surface RT?

Tags: partitioning, windows-rt

Luck is good for me and I can update Surface RT to Windows RT 8.1 before Microsoft delete the update from store. :)

But now is one problem. If I have one day to reset then I will have Windows RT 8 again?

I can update recovery partition of Surface RT so then reset will still have Windows RT 8.1? How? Please to give easy steps and excuse my English. :)

Comment: You can create a new recovery disk with Windows 8.1 which will of course recovery your system with Windows 8.1 installed.

Comment: Would that work for the arm models as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can download recovery images for all the Surface models from http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/warranty-service-and-recovery/downloadablerecoveryimage

This will let you install fresh Windows 8.1 even if you remove the recovery partition of the Surface.